# i want to print the outcome of the deep neural network,but" TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable" happen

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I want to print the outcome of the deep neural network, but" TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable" happen.

[image]

python

Comment: please revert to the past edit, pic of code is not helpful. The line of the error however is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in tensorflow, but looks like you are giving a DataFrame in the input_fn argument, when it should be a function. That's why it says it's not callable. Exactly this line is the problem:

```
predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=test_data))
```

Actually, looking into your code, you have other similar cases without this problem, in this line, where you actually pass a lambda function:

```
accuracy = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train_data), steps=100)
```

You can see some examples in the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets_for_estimators

Comment: change "predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=test_data))" to "predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(test_data)))"  and work!

Comment: Glad to help :) You should accept the answer if it solved the problem.